# Open same Finder window in different spaces

Tags: macos, finder, spaces

i was asking if someone knows a way to:

1. open a desktop folder
2. switch space
3. open the same folder without being brought back to the old space

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this. A workaround might be to assign Finder to All Desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! 
Simply right click on the finder icon on the dock, go to "Options" and then select "All Desktops". And voila! You have the same Finder window open anywhere and everywhere you need it!

Comment: This approach clutters up your space with a bunch of unnecessary finder windows by showing all finder windows in every space. The goal is just to have one finder window duplicated across 2 spaces.